# How to change default Column Header on WPF Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid whose ItemsSource is provided dynamically at run-time from a DB table.
For simplicity (?) I'm dumping the table contents into a 2-D array (the ItemsSource previously mentioned) because I don't know in advance how many columns any particular table may have.
Hence, AutoGenerate is set to True.

No problems with this - works fine; BUT the default behaviour of the grid is to number the columns from zero and display this number in the column header - I need them to number from one...
I've messed around with DisplayIndex, etc. but to no avail.
Anyone got any ideas on how I can alter/edit the default naming convention?

Just had a thought - would anyone suggest I catch the AutoGeneratedColumns event and manually count the columns then rename in a loop?
But of course the display to the user as the thing re-writes itself might be a bit strange... :)

Been a looong day - starting to babble!

I'm using VS2012 Express, the program is in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. It isn't possible to set 2-D array as ItemsSource.

If you use collection of entites then column header should be equal to property name.
If you'd like to change it, then there is an attribute called `DisplayName`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute%28VS.90%29.aspx